# How to remove Time from dateTime?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm getting **2019-09-10T00:00:00** as a response from API, So I want to remove the time part and want only **2019-09-10** as result.

```
$('<td>').text(item['Date']),
  $('<td>').text(item['Time In']),
$('<td>').text(item['Time Out'])
```

This is what my code is looking like, now I want to change these three.

Comment: `'2019-09-10T00:00:00'.substr(0,10)` does the job for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use split and split the date on 'T'

```js
 var a='2019-09-10T00:00:00';
 console.log(a.split('T')[0])
```

Comment: Hey,
What if I want "04:53:37 PM" from 2019-09-10T16:53:37 as output?

Comment: Use [1] instead of [0]

Comment: I did exactly the same but then I'm getting time as hh:mm:ss but I also want AM/PM with time.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a bit generic solution i-e by working with date objects.

```js
function formatDate(date, format ) {
  var dd = date.getDate();
  var mm = date.getMonth()+1; 
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
  
  if(dd<10) dd='0'+dd;
  if(mm<10) mm='0'+mm;

  switch(format) {
    case 'm-d-y': return mm+'-'+dd+'-'+yyyy;
    case 'm/d/y': return mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
    case 'd-m-y': return dd+'-'+mm+'-'+yyyy;
    case 'd/m/y': return dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
    default: return mm+'-'+dd+'-'+yyyy;
  }
}

const d = '2019-09-10T00:00:00';
console.log(formatDate(new Date(d), 'm/d/y'));
```

Comment: Given that this is just reordering of numbers that are already available in the original string, why use a Date object? And if that was to be the solution, there are already many questions and answers on [how to format a date](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+format+a+date).

Comment: lets say you get "2019-09-10 10:00 AM" as a date, in this scenario, the accepted answer will fail. 
And if we get the date string as "2019-11-1T00:00:00", the solution you proposed will be failed as well. ('2019-09-10T00:00:00'.substr(0,10))

Comment: Your answer will fail with `new Date("2019-11-1T00:00:00")` too. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) But that's not the OP format.